# How to get current geolocation when clicking a button?

Tags: android, geolocation

I would like to be able to retreive the user's current geolocation (latitude, longitude) and show it into a TextView when he presses a button in Android. I've tried some different strategies ([Android developer location strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)) but it doesn't show any location.

I believe it has something to do with the fact that the "onLocationChanged()" method is called when the user is moving but i couldn't find any documentation on that.

Here's my code (minSdkVersion is 24, which is why i've set up [the requesting permissions strategy](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html))

---

### CreateCustomStepActivity

---

```
public class CreateCustomStepActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView showLocation;
private Button scanGeolocationButton;
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1400;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_custom_step);
    showLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showLocationTextId);
    scanGeolocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanPositionButtonId);
    scanGeolocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CreateCustomStepActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CreateCustomStepActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                getCurrentGeolocation();
        }
    }
}

private void getCurrentGeolocation() {
    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) CreateCustomStepActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new UserLocationListener();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
// Define a listener that responds to location updates
private class UserLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
        String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
        String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude;
        showLocation.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}}
```

Comment: you can't be sure that the user location is already known when you press the button. So what you can do at most, is to request a location (change) reports. And in the callback - set the text into the TextView.

Comment: Sidenote: why are you using this ancient location api? Use fused location provider instead

Comment: `why are you using this ancient location api?` Well i think it used to work. No complains. So why changing a winning horse?

Comment: @greenapps it's not a winning horse. It's just a horse, and there are better horses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener`

Add a `GoogleApiClient` in `onCreate`

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

`connect` and `disconnect` the `mGoogleApiClient` from `onStart` and `onStop`

In `onConnected`:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setInterval(10); // Update location every second

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

In `onLocationChanged`, to get the output from the `textview` bind the view here:

```
txtOutput.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "\n"+Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
```

Comment: This is helpful but what is supposed to be "this" in this method?
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

When i type it in the onConnected() the IDE doesn't allow it

Comment: here 'this' means looper(3rd Argument) which means with continously request updates until you call removeUpdates